# Multivalue, Multidimensional Array as Single Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a multidimensional array:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [User_ID] => 1
                [Username] => A NAME
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [User_ID] => 2
                [Username] => ANOTHER NAME
            )
    )
```

I have seen how to flatten it...but say I want to do that and make it like so:

```
    Array
   (
       [1(As in the User_ID value)] => A NAME
       [2] => ANOTHER NAME
   )
```

Essentially creating a single array with the User_ID as the key and the Username as the value. How would I go about doing something like that? If it helps the list of IDs and Names could potentially be hundreds long, so it isn't a static number of items I am working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.5+, then there is actually a built-in function that can do this!  It's called [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

```
$newArray = array_column($yourArray, 'Username', 'User_ID');
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/182109

If you have a version of PHP lower than 5.5, then you can include this in your code to shim `array_column` in: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: Sweet. Now why didn't they think of that earlier? ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Because they wanted you to use a crazy mishmash of `array_map` and `array_combine` (or just a `foreach`) :-D

Comment: Their crazy little minds are constantly at work ;) Giving us better functions to work with later on, while eagerly waiting this happens (*while*) sipping Espressos and eating danishes at our favorite Café/Bistro.

Comment: I guess I don't have PHP5.5, but the little shim you provided worked. I will keep the array_column in mind for the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP versions < 5.5 or lacking the shim [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25450118/749181) by Rocket Hazmat, this will convert your array in to the necessary format:

```
<?php
$originalArray= array(
    0 => array(
        'User_ID' => 1,
        'Username' => 'A NAME'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'User_ID' => 2,
        'Username' => 'ANOTHER NAME'
    )
);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($originalArray as $element)
{
    $newArray[$element['User_ID']] = $element['Username'];
}
?>
```